# Is that statement true or false?

Tags: derivatives, proof-verification, sequence-of-function

Are following statements true or false ?

If function $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$, then the sequence n.$( f(x_0+(1/n)) - f(x_0))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is convergent.

I am really not sure, but I think it is true, but just because it seems to me so and I can't imagine any proof of it, would you help me ? Maybe it has something with Heine's sentence (a transition from function to sequence) but I see nothing in it. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: $n(f(x_0+1/n)-f(x_0))=\frac{f(x_0+1/n)-f(x_0)}{1/n}$. Use the definition of $f'(x_0)$.

Comment: Hello Janka, please use mathjax for formulas. Hint: look up the definition of the derivative.

Comment: And what should I do with that definition ? I am not very smart in derivations because we started with them only few days ago so I don't know what to do.

Comment: And how can I find out, if the sequence is convergent ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dfferentiability at $x_0$ implies continuity at $x_0$. In particular, 
$$\lim_n f\left(x_0+\frac{1}{n}\right) - f(x_0) = \lim_n \frac{f\left(x_0+\frac{1}{n}\right) - f(x_0)}{\frac{1}{n}} \cdot \frac{1}{n}.$$
You can evaluate each limit separately (limit of product is product of limits) to get $\lim_n \cdot = f^\prime(x_0) \cdot 0 =0$. So, yes the sequence converges (to zero).

Edit: It seems that I missed the $n$ in front. In that case,
$$\lim_n n\cdot \left(f\left(x_0+\frac{1}{n}\right) - f(x_0)\right) = \lim_n \frac{f\left(x_0+\frac{1}{n}\right) - f(x_0)}{\frac{1}{n}} = f^\prime(x_0).$$
Now that I've addressed the right question, does his make sense?

Comment: I still didn't get it, that "intersteps"